# Mismatch between sample SOAP request generated from server and the client SOAP message

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I am working on an application which expects a sample SOAP request message from the client which has been generated by the .svc file and has the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
   <GetInfo xmlns="http://sampleuri.org/">
     <GetInfoRequest>string</GetInfoRequest>
   </GetInfo>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope
```

The corresponding client's SOAP request has the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:10000/WcfSmsStringService.svc</To>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.sampleuri/soap/GetInfo</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetInfoRequest xmlns="http://www.sampleuri/soap">
            &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;
            &lt;GetInfoRequest xmlns=&quot;http://www.sampleuri/XMLSchema" /&gt;
        </GetInfoRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The client receives the following error:

EXCEPTION OCCURED
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 75 bytes of the response were: 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'.

Would you give me an appointment which is the best way to fix this problem?

Is there a way to change the sample SOAP request message which is automatically generated and expected from the server or there is another better approach?

After long research I still have not found a solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is with the utf-16 in the xml identification line.  Normally a just skip this line by opening up a streamreader and then ReadLine().   Then take the stream reader and feed into any standard xml deserialize method.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a SOAp 1.1 envelope, while the server is expecting SOAP 1.2. Notice the difference in SOAP namespaces between your messages.
Edit: At least, that is what I would say if the first few bytes of the response wouldn't say 'internal server error'. I would look for the cause of the problem on your server implementation. If the client message was invalid, you'd probably get some 'bad request' response.